# MVC5 redirect Controller action

Tags: jquery, redirect, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm a newbie using ASP.Net MVC5. I need to make a Jquery call to a controller to return a new view passing a single parameter. I can see plenty of examples that seem to refer to MVC3 and prior, but have struggled to find anything that handles MVC4 or MVC5 and works. All I want to do is get a value from an input element, pass it to a Controller ActionResult then open a new View.

PageTwo is the View and Home is the controller.

Code I've tried (amongst many others) that fails usually with 404:

window.location.href = '@UrlAction("PageTwo", "Home", new { id = imgId} )'; (where imgId is a variable and id is a controller action parameter).

or

var url = '@Html.Raw(Url.Action("PageTwo", "Home", new { id=imgId}))';
window.location.href = url;

I've also tried a standard Ajax call to the controller method.

I'm sure there's an easy answer ... I just can't find it..

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this. You get the img id and pass it to the method with a `jQuery` `$.post()`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o1h1myv6/1/)

```
<input type="text" value="2" class="img__id" />
<a href="/controller/action" class="click__me">click me</a>

$(document).on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        imgId = $('.img__id').val();

    $.post($this.attr('href'), { id: imgId });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you do it wrap the input around a form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ...
}
```

And redirect in the controller

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This i hope this will help for you

```
<script> 
      function setSelectedTestPlan(el) {
      window.open('/controller/action?img_id =" + img_id + "', '_blank');
    }
    </script>

<a onclick="setSelectedTestPlan(this);" href="javascript:void(0);">Click Me</a>
```